# how can I just put the search/filtered result on the top of the table grid without removing the other data

Tags: php, html, sql

so I made a search bar and it can filter the table but it always remove the other datas instead of just putting the result on the top of the grid.

Comment: share your code with us.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zfgax0hz252e59/php%20code.txt?dl=0


i cant insert my code so heres the link. thanks

Comment: Why can't you insert your code?

Comment: the stack doesn allow me to do so. always says that the code is longer that the desc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your previous search result, then you need to save it somewhere. Then you can attach your new result set with it. In you case, if you reload your page to search again, you can keep your data to session & change it after searching, lastly show it to users.

Add something like this before starting searching,

```
session_start();
```

`$_SESSION["result"] = "";`

Then after searching put your result data to session variable & show your result to users using that session data.

Comment: there would be instances that some record may be duplicated since all the record were stored in a session. any other options?

Comment: filter your array to remove that duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

I made two while loop, 1st loop will only show the searched/ filtered values and the second loop displays all except the displayed output of the first loop. thanks everyone! i really appreciate your help!